# Call all Javascript functions in a list

Tags: javascript

What is the most idiomatic way to call all functions in a list?

The best I can think of is:

```
myFunctions.forEach(function(f){f();});
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

EDIT:

I'm really only interested in ES5 for now. Perhaps there is some way having to do with Array prototypes?

Comment: "best way" is pretty open-ended, from what perspective?

Comment: Right, edited. I mean most idiomatic.

Comment: @eatonphil did one of the answers below help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about ES6?  You can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

This would be :

```
myFunctions.forEach( f => f());
```

You can already use it today with tool like [babel](https://babeljs.io/). For an overview of ES6 features check out [es6features](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features).

**EDIT:**

You can extend the `Array` object with the following method:

```
Array.prototype.invokeFunctions = function () {
    this.forEach(function (f) {
    if (typeof(f) === "function")
      f()
    });
}

var functions = [
    function () { console.log(1);},
    function () { console.log(2);}
];

functions.invokeFunctions();
// output 
1
2
```

However, I don't think this is a good idea as it pollutes the global Array prototype. A better idea could be to use an object designed explicitly for this purpose. For example:

```
function FunctionList(functions) {
  this.functions = functions;
}

FunctionList.prototype.callAll = function () {
  this.functions.forEach(function (f) {
    if (typeof(f) === "function")
      f()
  });
}

var functionList = new FunctionList(functions);
functionList.callAll();
```

This is a better solution in my opinion. Every time you have a function array you can wrap it in a `FunctionList` object. However in this case you lose all the benefits of using an Array and you have to implement getter and setter methods if you want to modify/access the function array.

Answer (score 2):

You could get tricky and use prototype methods, though it's not much more succinct:

```
myFunctions.map(Function.prototype.call, Function.prototype.call);
```

a wee bit shorter if you grab a reference to call:

```
var call = Function.prototype.call;
myFunctions.map(call, call);
```

or we could go nuts with prototype methods:

```
[].map.apply(fns, [call, call]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't say we couldn't use es6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ;)

```
funcs.forEach(x => x());
```

If you can't use es6, you can always use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 1):

```
function callEach(scope, funcs) {
  funcs.forEach(function (f) { f.call(scope); });
}

callEach(this, myFunctions);
```

I dunno, what you have seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the perfect use of `forEach`. Apart from ES6, the only thing I would do differently is pull out the function for readability:

```
var callSelf = function(funcToCall) {
    funcToCall();
}
```

Because then I can run:

```
myFunctions.forEach(callSelf);
```

Comment: Wouldn't call be the best choice

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you need the results or only side-effects. Here's with capturing the return values:

```
var results = fns.map(function(fn){return fn();});
```

Comment: The reason why I say this is because foreeach doesn't work well with promises

Answer (score 0):

Hm i use for-in for arrays, not for objects (beware).

```js
var ts = [function (){alert('a');}, function (){alert('b');}];
for (var tsIndex in ts) ts[tsIndex]();
```

Will alert `a` and `b`.

Beware: Do it with array only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some creative code, basically shifting the responsibility of determining which functions need to be called to the function itself.

```
function c() {
    console.log("c");
}

function b() {
    console.log("b");
    return c;
}

function a() {
    console.log("a");
    return b;
}

for(var f = a; f instanceof Function; f = f());
```